# How to disable globally backorders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

New products are being added daily to my website and it is unproductive to keep choosing the "Do not allow backorders" option for each new product and out of stock products. Currently with a growing database of over 2,000 products, I am finding it tedious to do the same process daily. Using the functions.php file, is there some php code I can implement to disallow backorders for all existing and future products?

Any help is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the following line of code to disable backorders globally:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

> In some cases, with some plugins you should define the priority hook, increasing it like:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false', 1000 );
> ```

---

For backorder notifications there is the `woocommerce_product_backorders_require_notification` filter.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help! 
The top code worked for me where as the bottom code took down my entire site.

Comment: @22WebDesign For this question, it is just the the first code for you (The other one is just to say that there is an other hook for backorder notifications).

Comment: Got it! Thank you sir.