# Disallow backorders product option globally (in admin too) on WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, backend

I have a question about how to disable backorders in WooCommerce globally. I found this here:

[How to disable globally backorders in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291624/how-to-disable-globally-backorders-in-woocommerce)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334083/woocommerce-is-it-possible-to-overide-the-settings-for-allowing-to-purchase-out

I use now `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false' );`. But is is still possible to set that option to allowed. So my question is, if I set a product to "Backorder allowed" and this snipped is active. After save the product "Backorder allowed" is visible. But is that only a display thing and in the back Backorder are not possible even if "allowed" is selected?

It would be nice, if there is no way to change that setting. Maybe gray-out that option in the edit product overview?

Is something possible?

Cheers

Comment: Can you pass priority `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false', 1000 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to disable backorder settings on admin product single pages *(that handle product variations too)*:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'disable_backorder_option_from_product_settings' );
function disable_backorder_option_from_product_settings() {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( in_array( $pagenow,  array('post-new.php', 'post.php') ) && $post_type === 'product' ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // For product variations
        $('#variable_product_options').on('change', function(){
            $('select[name^=variable_backorders]').each( function(){
                $(this).prop('disabled','disabled').val('no');
            });
        });
        // For all other product types
        $('select#_backorders').prop('disabled','disabled').val('no');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

For frontend, you will use additionally *(if there are still some older products with backorder option enabled)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false', 1000 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_require_notification', '__return_false', 1000 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_backorders', 'get_backorders_return_no' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_backorders', 'get_backorders_return_no' );
function get_backorders_return_no( $backorders ){
    return 'no';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_status', 'filter_product_stock_status', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_status', 'filter_product_stock_status', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_stock_status( $stock_status, $product ){
    return $product->get_manage_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ? 'outofstock' : $stock_status;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Awesome! Does this also mean, that now on all product on which backorder is currently allowed it is also disablet? Or do I need to add add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false' ); for that?

Comment: @Nik7 No, it only disables backorder option from admin product settings.

Comment: I see, so then I also need add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false' ); in order to disable it on every product right?

Comment: I tried this already. This is actually why I create this new question. If I use "add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false' );" then i still can change the backorder option to "allowd". The question then was, if that is just a display issue and in the backend is "not allowed" stored. So yeah, I tried this but that does not work for us. So then I was not sure how that snipped should work and if it is a issue on our system.

Comment: @Nik7 I updated my code to handle frontend product pages too, when backorder option is still enabled on some products.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec We just found an issue with this code above. When we use that, every product which is marked as "not manage stock" is displayed as "out of stock" in the admin product overview. The customer is able to buy, So i thinks it has something to do with that line here: return $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0  ? 'outofstock' : $stock_status;

Comment: @Nik7 Updated code… This issue should be solved now.